How can I refresh FlatList from pressing bottom bar tab?
I'm not able to find a correct way to refresh a FlatList when bottom bar tab is pressed and that we are at the top of the FlatList.
I did succeed to reach the top of the FlatList using useScrollToTop, also I managed to refetch data but it is not as I would like to be.
import { useScrollToTop } from '@react-navigation/native';

const flatlistRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);
useScrollToTop(flatlistRef);

This scroll to the top of the FlatList but :

I want to refetch only if top is already reached when pressing bottom bar tab
Using this I don't have the refresh control animation to see that something is refetching (it's just refetching underground)

I'm using React-Navigation for bottom tabs ("@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.16")
Any idea?
Thanks

Since you want to do more than just scroll to the top when the tab is focused, you should give up on using useScrollToTop and just use useFocusEffect. The hook is called whenever the current tab comes into focus. You can both refresh the data and scroll to the top of the flatlist in this hook (demo). To refresh when home screen is pressed is add a navigation listener for tab presses and then refresh there:
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  RefreshControl as RNRefreshControl,
  Platform
} from 'react-native';
import { RefreshControl as WebRefreshControl } from 'react-native-web-refresh-control'
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import useCountSeconds from './useCountSeconds';
import ListItem from './ListItem';
const RefreshControl = Platform.OS === 'web'
  ? WebRefreshControl
  :RNRefreshControl
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const flatlistRef = useRef();
  // counts seconds between lastRefresh and current time
  const { seconds, lastRefresh } = useCountSeconds(Date.now());
  const refreshData = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      // get sample data
      const data = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
      const json = await data.json();
      setData(json.products);
      // update lastRefresh
      lastRefresh.current = Date.now();
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [lastRefresh]);

  useFocusEffect(
    // must wrap function in callback to avoid
    // calling this effect alot
    useCallback(() => {
      console.log('Home screen focused');
      refreshData();
      flatlistRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0 });
    }, [refreshData])
  );
  // listen for Home tab presses
  useEffect(()=>{
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress',e=>{
      if(e.target.includes('Home')){
        console.log(e)
        refreshData()
      }
    })
    return ()=>{
      unsubscribe()
    }
  },[navigation,refreshData])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Refreshed: {seconds}s ago</Text>
      <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={{paddingTop:Platform.select({
            web:20,
            default:0
          })}}
          ref={flatlistRef}
          data={data}
          renderItem={(props) => <ListItem {...props} />}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          numColumns={2}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl refreshing={isLoading} onRefresh={refreshData} />
          }
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justigyContent: 'center',
  },
  listContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    margin: 10,
    padding: 5,
  },
});



https://snack.expo.dev/CvP8t5tUAmtHv5sKKawLu

Thanks a lot, but it's triggered only on focus. I try to go on top on tab press and if already on top then : refetch FlatList. Yours only refetch if coming from another tab and focusing that one. My solution works but it looks a bit dirty, any idea how I could achieve that properly?

Just add RefreshControl. I dont know if you intend to support web, but the React Native's default RefreshControl doesnt work for web so I found a component that still sucks at working for web, but works better than the RN version

https://snack.expo.dev/PilXKUb6wl08MDALkd5Od

Your example doesn't work as expected. Again pressing Home tab when already on the home screen should :

go at the top of the FlatList if not already at the top otherwise it should trigger a refetch of the FlatList (exactly as it would do if you pull to refresh the FlatList)


Attempting to navigate to the same page that you are on would not start a navigation event unless you navigate to the same page with different route parameters I think

Yes then this doesn't answer initial question. Any idea to answer initial question?

Sorry in the solution you provided you didnt address this problem so I thought it was a nonissue. I've updated the answer to work as intended

Found a solution to this — might be better answer if so feel free to respond!
const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState<boolean>(false);
const flatlistRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);
const scrollPositionRef = useRef(0);

const refetchControl = async () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true);
    await refetchAPIEndpoint();
    setIsRefreshing(false);
};

const handleScroll = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
    scrollPositionRef.current = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
};

const scrollToTop = async () => {
    if (scrollPositionRef.current === 0) {
        await refetchControl();
        flatlistRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0 });
    } else {
        flatlistRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0 });
    }
}

useScrollToTop(
    useRef({ scrollToTop }),
);

return (
    <FlatList
        ...
        ref={flatlistRef}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={isRefreshing} onRefresh={refetchControl} />}
    />
);

Didn't really understand useScrollToTop(useRef({ scrollToTop })) this, but it works — feel free to explain!
